# ZF2 View within view

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to make an interface with the following behaviour:

```
HTML output for /a/.
<ul>
<li>html output for /a/1/</li>
<li>html output for /a/2/</li>
<li>html output for /a/3/</li>
</ul>
```

So at a guess the view for /a/ will run a function which gets the html for each of /a/1/, /a/2/, etc.

Obviously my router would contain two separate controller functions for /a/ and /a/[:number] and my controller function for /a/[:number] would return a ViewModel with setTerminal(true).

I could call each of those URLs with ajax once the page has loaded, and the reason I am doing it this way is that I will want to ajax update those pieces of html individually later, but on the first call it should be faster to render those parts of the HTML on the call to /a/.

As I see it, I need a function which returns the HTML for /a/[:number]/, so my **question** is, how do I do that? What function can I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd write a view helper (extending Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper). The view helper would need the following information:

- the route to render
- the allowed parameters to render (i.e. 1-10)

In your view you'd call the view-helper like:

```
$this->linkGenerator('a', array(1, 10)); //render all from /a/1 to /a/10
```

Your view helper would look something like this:

```
namespace Mynamespace\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class LinkGenerator extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($routeName, array $range)
    {
        return $this->getView()->render('mynamespace/view/helper/linkgenerator.phtml', array(
            'route' => $routeName,
            'range' => $range
        ));
    }
}
```

And finally your `linkgenerator.phtml` would look like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($this->range as $value) : ?>
    <li>
         <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('id', $value));?>">
             ####RouteLabel!?
         </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Now the route-label would be one of the more trickier things. Since ID's would have different labels (assumingly) you'd probably need to call either a navigation configuration or your database from your viewhelper and fetch the labels accordingly.

The injection of the tableGateway/Mapper/EntityRepository would be done within the `__construct()` function.

You'd inject the needed stuff via the factory you assign when registering your view helper like this:

```
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'linkGenerator' => function ($sm) {
                    $someDependency= $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('some-dependency');

                    return new \Mynamespace\View\Helper\LinkGenerator($someDependency); //<- this is for __construct() ;)
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

Hope this covers your question. I guess everything else would boil down to javascript.

Comment: I'm quite new to zf2, can you clarify for me what 'some-dependency' refers to? I have:

`'invokables' => array(
    'some-dependency' => 'MyModule\Helper\LinkGenerator',
),`

But I get an error `ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for some-dependency`.

Comment: `'some-dependency'` in this case may be another dependency that you need to make the LinkGenerator work. It is not THE LinkGenerator. It could be the `tableGateway` or a `Repository` of some sort. Because you will need to know how many links to put out, can't be done by magic, so my assumption is that you will need some kind of dependency injection in there ;)

Comment: I actually used the invokables section of my module config in the end since I had no need for a special constructor. Thanks for the information though, it did help me climb the steep learning curve.

Comment: I am unable to get a link to the view though.. I am getting 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template'. Any tips on where I should put the phtml file and how to link to it properly please? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisBorg You need to map the template properly. template_map key of your configuration inside the view_manager key.